# Website looks different using domain than when I use IP

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, cloud-hosting

I've just hosted a website using DigitalOcean and got a domain from GoDaddy. Everything works great however when I started making changes and uploading them via filezilla, these changes are only made when I go to my IP address of the site. If I go to the domain these changes do not take effect. This is extremely weird and I cannot find anything mentioning this anywhere. Does anyone know what the issue might be? It has been a day and no changes have taken place.

Thanks.

In Addition this domain seems to crash or go offline and I cannot access my website with it while if I use the direct IP I can.

Comment: It looks like DNS issue. Just ping your domain, what is the result? Has your domain point to DigitalOcean IP address?

Comment: Maybe this issue is related to DNS propagation. Check your current DNS status here https://www.whatsmydns.net

Answer (score 0):

Happens all the time, make sure your domain is setup properly in your account and that it is pointing to your host's servers [How to Point to DigitalOcean Nameservers](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-point-to-digitalocean-nameservers-from-common-domain-registrars)

Also make sure you upload to the same directory (ie. /public_html/), if you have problems pinpointing this directory contact your host for support.